# Creating time blocks for each date and populating presence data

Tags: r, database, date, time, datatable

I am trying to create a data set of 15min time blocks for each date in my data set going from 19:45:00 in the evening until 06:30:00 in the morning. Then I am trying to count the number of times a species is present/absent in each of those time blocks, essential grouping it by site, date, 15min time block. I have multiple sites over multiple nights.

I have been able to group the data by hour etc. but this doesn't fix that it only counts when the species is present and doesn't create 0's when the species is absent (as there is no timestamp).

The sample data is below. I can give more data if needed.

```
Site <- ("1831", "1803", "1803", "1807", "1807", "1807", "1807")
Date <- as.Date("05/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "08/05/2013", "08/05/2013")
Time <- c("23:31:29", "22:22:57", "22:04:47", "22:58:45", "01:24:15", "22:04:47")
Present <- as.numeric("1", "1", "0", "1","0", "1", "1")
data <- data.frame(Site, Date, Time, Present)
```

The reason why there are some 0's in the present column is that the detector triggered but it wasn't the species we were looking for.

In theory, it should look something like this for the first date and site in the example (but for each site and the multiple dates within them):

[image]

Comment: A few questions I have. The sample data you provided does not make a data frame, elements have different lengths. Can you provide another sample, using probably structure() or dput() commands? The times you provided are not with 15 minute intervals. If your original data looks like the picture you provided, you can just use an aggregate function, like this: aggregate(cbind(Present = Present) ~ Date + Site + Time, data = data, function(x) }{NROW(x)})

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `lubridate` package and its `floor_date` function, you can round down to the nearest 15 minutes. This allows you to `left_join` your data onto a complete listing of all times at all sites obtained by `grid.expand`.

Your data was not reproducible, as the code to produce it contained some errors - I had to alter the code slightly to get the data into a coherent data frame. The following should make the data reproducible:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

Site    <- c("1831", "1803", "1803", "1807", "1807", "1807", "1807")
Date    <- dmy(c("05/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", 
              "06/05/2013", "08/05/2013", "08/05/2013"))
Time    <- c("23:31:29", "22:22:57", "22:04:47", "22:58:45", "01:24:15", 
          "22:04:47", "03:45:02")
Present <- as.numeric(c("1", "1", "0", "1","0", "1", "1"))
data    <- data.frame(Site, Date, Time, Present)
```

The first thing I did was to combine the dates and times into unified date-times to make the left joining easier, and round them down to the closest 15 minutes:

```
data$date_time <- floor_date(as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time)),
                             "15 minutes")
```

Next we get all possible times by getting each date from your data and adding a sequence of 15 minutes starting from 19:45 to 06:30 the following morning to each of them:

```
all_times <- do.call(c, sapply(unique(data$Date), 
                               function(x) x +  minutes(15) * seq(75, 118, 1)))
```

Now to facilitate the left join we can drop the columns we no longer need from `data`:

```
data <- data[, c("Site", "date_time", "Present")]
```

We next create a data frame with a column of all times at all sites:

```
df <- expand.grid(date_time = all_times, Site = unique(data$Site))[2:1]
df$date_time <- as.POSIXct(df$date_time)
```

Finally we left join our data to this new data frame, filling the resulting `NA` values with 1s:

```
df <- left_join(df, data, by = c("Site", "date_time")) 
df$Present[is.na(df$Present)] <- 0
```

Our resulting data frame is 396 rows long, so I will show only the first 20 rows here:

```
head(df, 20)
#>    Site           date_time Present
#> 1  1831 2013-05-05 19:45:00       0
#> 2  1831 2013-05-05 20:00:00       0
#> 3  1831 2013-05-05 20:15:00       0
#> 4  1831 2013-05-05 20:30:00       0
#> 5  1831 2013-05-05 20:45:00       0
#> 6  1831 2013-05-05 21:00:00       0
#> 7  1831 2013-05-05 21:15:00       0
#> 8  1831 2013-05-05 21:30:00       0
#> 9  1831 2013-05-05 21:45:00       0
#> 10 1831 2013-05-05 22:00:00       0
#> 11 1831 2013-05-05 22:15:00       0
#> 12 1831 2013-05-05 22:30:00       0
#> 13 1831 2013-05-05 22:45:00       0
#> 14 1831 2013-05-05 23:00:00       0
#> 15 1831 2013-05-05 23:15:00       0
#> 16 1831 2013-05-05 23:30:00       1
#> 17 1831 2013-05-05 23:45:00       0
#> 18 1831 2013-05-06 00:00:00       0
#> 19 1831 2013-05-06 00:15:00       0
#> 20 1831 2013-05-06 00:30:00       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using non-equi join from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#generate intervals
ans <- setDT(data)[, {
    s <- c(seq(as.POSIXct(paste(d, "00:00:00")), as.POSIXct(paste(d, "06:15:00")), "15 mins"),
        seq(as.POSIXct(paste(d, "19:45:00")), as.POSIXct(paste(d, "23:45:00")), "15 mins"))
    .(s=s, e=s+15*60)
}, .(Site, d=as.Date(Date))]

#non-equi join and update by reference
ans[, p := 
    data[Present==1L][.SD, on=.(Site, Date>=s, Date<=e), by=.EACHI, sum(Present, na.rm=TRUE)]$V1
]
```

output for `ans[p==1L]`

```
   Site          d                   s                   e p
1: 1831 2013-05-05 2013-05-05 23:30:00 2013-05-05 23:45:00 1
2: 1803 2013-06-05 2013-06-05 22:15:00 2013-06-05 22:30:00 1
3: 1807 2013-06-05 2013-06-05 22:45:00 2013-06-05 23:00:00 1
4: 1807 2013-08-05 2013-08-05 21:00:00 2013-08-05 21:15:00 1
5: 1807 2013-08-05 2013-08-05 22:00:00 2013-08-05 22:15:00 1
```

data:

```
   Site                Date Present
1: 1831 2013-05-05 23:31:29       1
2: 1803 2013-06-05 22:22:57       1
3: 1803 2013-06-05 22:04:47       0
4: 1807 2013-06-05 22:58:45       1
5: 1807 2013-06-05 01:24:15       0
6: 1807 2013-08-05 22:04:47       1
7: 1807 2013-08-05 21:04:47       1
```

code for data:

```
Site <- c("1831", "1803", "1803", "1807", "1807", "1807", "1807")
Date <- as.POSIXct(paste(c("05/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2013", "08/05/2013", "08/05/2013"),
        c("23:31:29", "22:22:57", "22:04:47", "22:58:45", "01:24:15", "22:04:47", "21:04:47")),
    format="%m/%d/%Y %T")
Present <- as.integer(c(1, 1, 0, 1,0, 1, 1))
data <- data.frame(Site, Date, Present)
```

Comment: I managed to create the 'ans' data but the join did not work for me. I managed to join the data another way though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show some examples where it is not working?